# tokeninput jquery php : show all results ever

Tags: php, jquery, json

i need help on my script.

I create my file PHP :

```
# Perform the query
$query = sprintf("SELECT ID,CATEGORIA from INTUITcategoria ORDER BY CATEGORIA", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

# Collect the results
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

# Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

and JSON result seems ok and is this :

> ```
> {"ID":"73","CATEGORIA":"RADIOMICROFONI"},
> {"ID":"68","CATEGORIA":"ACCESSORI RADIOMICROFONI"},  {"ID":"34","CATEGORIA":"ACCORDATORI "}, ............
> ```

Now set my html file in this way :

```
>     <div>
>         <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="blah2" />
>         <input type="button" value="Submit" />
>         <script type="text/javascript">
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>             $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("../categorieautocomplete.php",
> {
>                 theme: "facebook"
>             });
>         });
>         </script>
>     </div>
```

But i have a problem.
When i digit "ACC" into input text, i receive entire list and not filter on "ACC".

Have an ideas for solve this ?

Thank's in advance

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("../categorieautocomplete.php",
```

You are not passing the parameter to the script, so if it is empty then it give you all rows. You need to pass the "q" parameter to the script.

Comment: I try to append "q" parameter in this way : $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("../categorieautocomplete.php?q=query", but not working. Is correct ?

Comment: That value must contain the variable "q" ?

Comment: I try to assign to q parameter more and different parameter but script not work ing. i don't understand what value assign to q.